# Copy a list with an element inserted in Python

Tags: python, list, insert, copy

I have the following code which makes a copy(cpy) of a list (lst), inserts a given element (e) at a specific position (i), and then appends it to another list (rlst):

```
        cpy = lst[:]
        cpy.insert(i,e)
        rlst.append(cpy)
```

is there a more elegant way of doing this, which would result in a one liner? something like:

```
rlst.append("Some code here")
```

Comment: You're doing 3 actions, each one of them requires *only* one line. Doing more than one action in a line is bad practice: it makes the code less readable as well as more difficult to debug in case of errors. Have you heard about the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) ?

Comment: @alfasin: which is why people prefer to code in assembler, rather than those unreadable modern languages that allow arbitrarily-complicated expressions ;-)

Comment: @alfasin:  That was my thought as well, but the one-liner ends up as quite readable.  I would actually understand the one-liner more quickly than the original.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski if `lst` is messed up (`None` or something other than a list), if `i` is invalid or if there are any other issues that I'm not thinking about right now - it'll probably be easier to discover with the 3 lines rather than the one line. BTW, that's a guideline that is good to *any* programming language: don't do too many things in the same line of code.

Comment: @alfasin:  Those scenarios would provide an informative exceptions and tracebacks.  I agree heartily with your general point, but I feel that it does not apply here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a case where a one-liner doesn't hurt readability:

```
rlst.append(lst[:i] + [e] + lst[i:])
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do list comprehension you could do:
(let i be the desired index, e = value)

```
rlst.append([y if x is not i else e for x,y in enumerate(cpy)])
```

Comment: Not quite.  Insert doesn't overwrite at the index.  (Downvote is because the code is buggy.)

Comment: As well as that, I have my doubts whether `x is not i` works for indices greater than 255.